# Add a custom URI to an existing Windows application (Excel in this case)

Tags: c#, excel, windows, vsto

I have a custom URI `alsdk:f12o4ijf1qoi4j` which I would like to click on as an `href` in a web browser, have it open Excel, and pass the `f12o4ijf1qoi4j` data to a C# VSTO add-in.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

The Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) only refer to new applications, not adding a URI association to an existing application like Excel. (And no, I can not change the `alsdk` URI itself.)

Thanks!